# How to add external data to a DataFrame x based on the content available in the columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

We have a file with references which should be resolved in data linked to those references. Each reference can be in a different file (which can be determined based on the reference).

The data set looks like:

| ref | year | month | day | filepath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bla2 | 2022 | 9 | 2 | subpath/2022/9/1/ |
| bla1 | 2023 | 1 | 2 | subpath/2023/1/1/ |
| blabla | 2023 | 3 | 4 | subpath/2023/3/4/ |

The referenced file have all the following structure:

| ref | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bla1 | a lot of data | something |
| ... | ... | DDd |
| aazed | a lot of data | X |

Question:
How can I, once the above is loaded into a dataframe; append given data from the referenced item in the referenced file?

The access to the external files is via partitioned data (see the included path), which I can calculate as an additional column to the source dataframe.

For info:

- The first part with the index file and enriching it has been done using pure pyspark and Dataframe/RDD.
- Expecting a way on how to solve this "enriching" of the data and hopefully some examples.

Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I've since found the answer (was looking at it the wrong way).

For info:

All lookup values where already in partitioned path `blabla/blabla/contextType=*/year=*/month=*/day=*` (referenced as `rootInputPath` here under.)

So it just required to d-do the following using the `indexdf` already containing the source elements (year, month,day, refId):

```
lookup = spark.read.parquet(f"{rootInputPath}" )
lookup = exchange_df.filter( "traType in (1,11)")
lookup = lookup .select("year","month","day","contextType","refId","shopId","time","productId")

join_cond = [(lookup.year == indexdf.year) & (lookup.month == indexdf.month) & (lookup.day == indexdf.day) & (lookup.refId == indexdf.refId)]
result = indexdf.join(lookup, join_cond, "left")
```

Works fine for the moment, probably not at the greatest speed but enough to make me happy.